Past tenses and the difference in meaning
We use past continuous to show a longer background action and past simple to show a shorter one that quite often interacts with the longer one. Is it possible to sometimes use past simple instead of continuous to say something faster? For instance
A) When I was repairing his car he paid me a visit
Vs
B) When I repaired his car he paid me a visit
If I used the B version would I communicate the same meaning as A does? I mean a single situation not something that happened many times.

No, you can't put it that way 'to say it faster'. To me, B suggests that you once repaired his car some time ago and you are recalling the day when that happened.

When in (B) would almost always mean (or be assumed to mean) after, not while. But for the avoidance of doubt / ambiguity, I suggest you always use after or while in your own text.

@FumbleFingers what if B was a situation that happened many times?. Not just once. I Think in that case it is similar to A

That's such a pragmatically unlikely meaning in general that I can't imagine a situation where it would be contextually obvious you were talking about something that often happened as a routine. So if that was the intended sense, you'd use different words to make it unambiguously clear. Just don't use when like this - use after or while and stop inventing "linguistic non-problems".

No, they aren't the same.
'Repairing a car' could be a process that takes hours. During that time, the car is not 'repaired'. It is in a state of disrepair until it is finally fixed.
For an action to occur while that process is still taking place, you need to use the past continuous tense. Your second example sounds like he visited you after you had finished the repair.
"A visit" makes it clear that there was just one visit during that time.

If I use "whenever"  instead of "when" in B to to show that it happened many time, then I think it happenes to be more similar to A, doesn't it?

@BobBob Ah so you're talking about both parts of this scenario being a regular occurrence? You'd often repair his car, and he would visit you while you were repairing it? Well, yes... 'whenever' would do it. But I have more questions now. Is 'he' the same person? How does the car get to you in the first place? Does he visit to bring the car, and then visit again while you're working, and then visit again to collect it when it's done being fixed? All sounding a bit weird. I think you need to spell out exactly what happens, in sequence, and then maybe we can answer.

I. Simple Present and Present Continuous meaning
OP's query:

A) When I was repairing his car he paid me a visit.
Vs.
B) When I repaired his car he paid me a visit.
If I used the B version would I communicate the same meaning as A does?

Both sentences have different meanings:
Sentence A means that the repair of the car was ongoing when the visit happened.
Sentence B implies that the visit happened on the completion of the repair.
II. Single or multiple situation.

I mean a single situation not something that happened many times.

If you wanted to convey that this situation happened multiple times, you should rephrase your sentences
A) When I was repairing his car, he would often pay me a visit".
B) "Whenever I repaired his car, he paid me a visit".
However, the difference in meaning between the two sentences remains the same.
.
